# sorry an unexpected error happened in mysql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I'm creating the stored procedure in MySql  as like below :

```
DELIMITER $$

Create procedure LoginVerify (p_UserName  varchar(50),p_Password varchar(50))
begin
select UserDetailID, First_Name, Last_Name, Email_Address, `User_Name` from user_details where `User_Name`=p_UserName and `Password`=p_Password
end

DELIMITER ;
```

After executing the above procedure I'm getting usually an exceptional message as like "sorry an unexpected error happened mysql"
How to resolve that ? I had gone through same queries in stackoverflow, As they are saying the problem with delimeters. But I didn't get proper solution.

Comment: There end statement needs a delimiter ($$) and the select needs a terminator, but since there is only 1 statement you don't need begin and it's matching end or to set delimiters

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks. It got executed after removing the delimeters and begin and end. When to use delimeters then ?Thanks once again.

Comment: Don't store plain text passwords in the database. In a stored procedure, a salted hash with each row having a unique salt is probably one of the better options.

Comment: 'When to use delimeters then' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html